# What are different padding modes and cipher modes in IPhone for AES encryption?

Tags: iphone, encryption

What are different padding modes and cipher modes in IPhone for AES encryption?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

There are two padding modes--PKCS #7 and none--and two corresponding cipher modes--CBC and ECB. If you specify `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` then you get CBC and if you specify `kCCOptionECBMode` then there's no padding and you get ECB. The default is CBC, according the [CommonCrypto header](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-32207/CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h).